# How to use an adverb like “untenably” in a sentence with having it sound wrong?

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, adverbs, syntactic-analysis

I am trying to use untenably in a sentence.  Not to showcase my 
ignorance, but I feel like the modern usage is out of whack with the
grammar rules.  The sentence in question is:

1. Marin was getting ***untenably* expensive**.

Here *untenably* is an adverb, but modifies *expensive*.  So, it should 
properly be *untenable expensive* instead.

2. Marin was getting ***untenable* expensive**.

But that sounds archaic to my ear.

Also, I am having a tough time coming up with the correct usage of
*untenably* as an adverb. Something seems wrong with these but I don't know what:

3. She untenably ran...
4. She untenably worked...

Can someone enlighten me here? Why does sentence 2 sound wrong? Why don't sentences 3 and 4 sound right?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. What did you find when you Googled 'untenably' ?

Comment: No. Adverbs modify adjectives; adjectives do not modify adjectives.

Comment: http://wordnik.com/words/untenably  Expand the *Examples* section.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done
. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: As far as I can tell, these comments and the one answer mean to agree that OP's sentence 1, "Marin was getting untenably expensive," is correct.

Comment: And *expensive* is an adjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence appears to use *untenable* with the meaning suggested below meaning excessive or insupportable. *Untenably* is correct according to this excerpt from *The Free Dictionary* online, which originally came from the *American Heritage Dictionary*. See in particular “[Usage Note](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/untenably)” where it elaborates on why sense 3 of *untenable* is one that some may considered to have a usage problem:

> 1. Not capable of being maintained or defended: an untenable position.
> 2. Not capable of being occupied or lived in: untenable quarters.
> 3. *Usage Problem* Insupportable; intolerable.
>
>    ***Usage Note:*** The word *untenable* has recently been applied to various situations with the meaning "***not capable of being coped with; insupportable.***" This meaning (which is not far from the traditional sense of "incapable of being maintained") has become codified in the locution *untenable situation*.
>
>    In our 2005 survey, fully 91 percent of the Usage Panel found this expression acceptable in the sentence *The job offer left her in an untenable situation: She must either move away from her child or forgo her dream of becoming a film director.* But the Panel had little enthusiasm when *untenable* was extended in its application with this meaning. Only 19 percent accepted the sentence *Another untenable tragedy in the region is that children have dropped out of school to become soldiers.* The Panel became even less sanguine when *untenable* was applied to an emotional burden, with just 12 percent accepting *When I saw the destruction from the storm, a sense of untenable sadness washed over me.*

(AHD)

Comment: When I searched I got:
https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/untenable .
I was under the false impression that adverbs modified verbs alone, and not adjectives.  
I was also interested in the evolving usage of the word.  I'll have to check out the Free Dictionary Online.  Though I was warned away from that site a while ago due to bloat, but maybe it's not really as bad?  That's maybe off topic for this thread.
Thanks!